# Doctrine2 Multi-level inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I've been trying to map multi-level inheritance with doctrine2, here's the UML :
[image]

Each class maps a SQL table, the mapping looks like this :

```
   /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="PERSONS")
     * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="PERSON_TYPES", type="string")
     * @DiscriminatorMap({"INSUREE" = "Insuree", "ADMIN" = "Admin"})
     */
    abstract class Person extends Entity{}

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="INSUREES")
     * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="INSUREE_TYPES", type="string")
     * @DiscriminatorMap({"CUSTOMER" = "Customer", "THIRD_PARTY" = "ThirdParty"})
     */
    abstract class Insuree extends Person{}

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="ADMINS")
     */
    final class Admin extends Person implements User{}

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="CUSTOMERS")
     */
    final class Customer extends Insuree implements User{}

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="EXPERTS")
     */
    final class Expert extends Person{}
```

When I try to find all customers or any other concrete classes I got this error :

> Uncaught Doctrine\Instantiator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The provided class "Insuree" is abstract, and can not be instantiated in ...

I found a project on github whose the mapping hierarchy is similar to mine and works fine :

https://github.com/paulandrieux/MultipleInheritanceSandbox/tree/master/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity

EDIT :

After putting all discriminators to the top class (Person), Doctrine skips inserting data into INSUREES table when I try to persist a new Customer as I get this error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID, ID_CARD, SEPA) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [10, "", ""]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aaa`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `INSUREES` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)"

Here's my CREATE TABLE sql script :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  CITY VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  ZIP_CODE BIGINT(5) NULL,
  TEL VARCHAR(13) NULL,
  PERSON_TYPES ENUM("ADMIN","EXPERT","THIRD_PARTY","CUSTOMER"),
  MAJ TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INSUREES(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
  BONUS_MALUS REAL(5,2) DEFAULT 1.0,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES PERSONS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS THIRD_PARTIES(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
  COMPAGNY VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES INSUREES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXPERTS(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  RANK BIGINT(4) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES PERSONS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)comment = "";

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMERS(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ID_CARD VARCHAR(100),
  SEPA VARCHAR(100),
  FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES INSUREES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADMINS(
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   ROLE VARCHAR(128) NULL, 
   FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES PERSONS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

Comment: That external example you showed us is different because they do not use base class as a table in a database. You in your code use base classes also as tables in a database so you have errors.

Comment: Every classes is annotated with @Entity.

Comment: Check your annotations and his. They are different, trust me ;) And he doesn't build queries with abstract entities.

Comment: can you post the query or how you try to find e.g. all Customers? The inheritance looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allowed to define the InheritanceType, DiscriminatorColumn and DiscriminatorMap in the topmost class [Doctrine class-table-inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) which is in your case **Person**.

I would suggest the following:

```
   /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="PERSONS")
     * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="PERSON_TYPES", type="string")
     * @DiscriminatorMap({
            "INSUREE" = "Insuree", 
            "ADMIN" = "Admin",
            "CUSTOMER" = "Customer",
            "EXPERT" = "Expert"
        })
     */
    abstract class Person extends Entity{}

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="INSUREES")
     */
    abstract class Insuree extends Person{}
```

Update:

Your database-scheme should look something like this:
[image: database-scheme]
where *interface_task* is person in your case. You do this with all of your child-classes (and child-child-classes), all pointing to the super-class and the id is a foreign-key pointing to the id of the super-class interface_task (person in your case)

also be sure, you add an on-delete cascade to the foreign key, so that if you delete a child-class also the parent-class in the database gets deleted

Comment: I changed the mapping like this, it had seemed to work fine until I created a Customer; Doctrine's Insert query skips the INSUREES table and proceeds like this :
insert person data -> insert customer data as I get a nice Integrity constraint violation.

Comment: you need a table for each entity, each table has an foreign-key pointing to the id of your top-most class (Person) with a on-delete cascade

Comment: I just updated my question : I've added the 'create table' script.

Comment: Sorry for answering this late but I've finally solved the problem by doing like this. First I had MySQL constraint errors because I was doing mysql inheritance the way I was doing OOP inheritance :
Insurees table had a foreign key pointing to Persons and Customers and ThirdParties had one pointing to Insurees while their must have pointed on Persons as well.